# MySQL query select all and get different results from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am building a blog but I am stuck at the query. What I am trying to do, is to list all post (sliders, videos, texts), but however all of those have different table structure. 
There is a table called Post that stores ID, post_type, post_date. 
All post table has ID that is the same as Post ID

Should I do a

```
left join where slider.id = post.id ; videos.id = post.id ?
```

Comment: please show us the database structure for all of the involved tables.

Comment: Post table: id, post_type (images, texts, videos), insert_date
    image: id, images (separated by ;), insert_date; image_id
    texts: id, texts, insert_date, text_id